# Can't get fancybox to load

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. In wordpress, loaded up the easy fancybox plugin to load in all the necessary files but I can't get anything to work. I've tried galleries, single images, iframes.

I don't see any clashes with other plugins, only one jquery version is loading.

I basically copied the code form the site where everything is loading fine:
http://www.familypet.com/photos/

And this is the current one where it isn't loading:
http://testwp.familypet.com/photo-gallery/

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you anchors suppose to have the class `fancybox` but they have `fancybox-iframe` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://testwp.familypet.com/photo-gallery/ site you are missing **iframe javascript code** but you are using **fancybox-iframe classes**.

That code is not missing in http://www.familypet.com/photos/

Try adding this code to the testwp site and put it above `/* Auto-click */` comment (line 151):

```
/* iFrame */
$('a.fancybox-iframe, li.fancybox-iframe a, area.fancybox-iframe, li.fancybox-iframe a').fancybox( $.extend({}, fb_opts, { 'type' : 'iframe', 'width' : 950, 'height' : 550, 'padding' : 0, 'scrolling' : 'auto', 'autoScale' : false, 'titleShow' : true, 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 'titleFromAlt' : true }) );
```